# How to break this circular typedef?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, typedef, forward-declaration

I want to declare a couple of types
(internal to a class templated on `K` and `V` and providing some caching behaviour):

```
typedef std::map<
  long long,
  typename key_to_value_type::iterator  // Ooops... not declared yet
> timestamp_to_key_type;

typedef std::map<
  K,
  std::pair<V,typename timestamp_to_key_type::iterator> 
> key_to_value_type;
```

Of course this isn't possible as is, because of the circular definition.
I could hack it with a `void*`, but I'm wondering if there's some forward-declaration magic or other technique which will do the job better.

(Yes I am aware a `boost::bimap` would sidestep the problem).

Comment: Are you trying to build a map with data, and then an index of that map in a different order? (Presumably for speedy lookup)

Comment: The question came up while I was fooling around with some already working LRU-caching code (basically a key-value map supplemented with tracking so the least recently used records can be purged when needed).  The original version has each map's value hold the key type of the other map, but some O(log n) accesses could be squashed to direct iterator accesses using the form above.  But I don't want this question to turn into a debate about the merits of LRU-cache implementations!  It was more that I realized I didn't know how best to handle this sort of typedef/forward-declaration problem.

Comment: +1 That's a good question. If only I knew what's the type you're aiming to express.

Comment: For more details on where this came up, see http://www.bottlenose.demon.co.uk/article/lru.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible, consider what the types would be:

```
timestamp_to_key_type
= map< long long, key_to_value_type::iterator >
= map< long long, map< K, pair< V, timestamp_to_key_type::iterator > >::iterator >
= map< long long, map< K, pair< V, map< long long, map< K, pair< V, map< long long, map< K, pair < V ...
```

This is not a problem with forward declarations, you are simple trying to describe a type that is recursively defined on itself. It's no different than:

```
struct A { B b; };
struct B { A a; };
```

The only way to get around this is to lose some static type information. As you said, you can use `void*`, or you can try to define your own abstract, type-erased interface. Your choice.

Comment: isn't this more like having each structure have pointers to the other struct? He has iterators, not the type in itself, so I don't think the problem lies with this

Comment: iterators aren't necessarily a pointer. They can be, and often are, classes. Peter is correct in his analysis.

Comment: He has T = map<A, B> where the type of B is defined in terms of T. It's not structurally recursive like my analogy, but the types are recursive, and C++ does not support recursive types.

Comment: @Dasaruga I think that's right. But in that case the language allows the self-reference (i.e the type-graph of `struct A { A *a; }` will contain a cycle, but that's fine). However there are other cases where it isn't allowed. You cannot have a function that returns a pointer to itself or a parameter to itself, typewise.

Comment: @litb - Yeah, I think that's a better comparison :-)

Answer (score 1):

Break the circular definition with only one of them containing the V and the other containing the iterator:

```
typedef map<K, V> KVMap;
typedef map<long long, typename KVMap::iterator> TSMap;
```

If you need to use a key to look up a timestamp, and that timestamp isn't stored in V, then you can duplicate that in KVMap:

```
typedef map<K, pair<V, long long> > KVMap;
```

From a K, you can use KVMap::find, get the timestamp, and then use TSMap::find and get a handle on the corresponding item (e.g. to erase it).